# Spring Jaxb2Marshaller - Date issue

Tags: java, spring, date, jaxb2

I am seeing a curious thing happening when deserializing an XML response into a POJO object, specifically a date field. Here are the details:

- The date field is represented as a long value when serializing/deserializing. The long value is supposed to be the time in millis since epoch (1970).
- It is happening only for old dates (before 1970) where the long value is actually negative
- The issue is that during deserialization, the negative long value is  parsed into a date object with an additional offset
- For example, if the actual value is:

  - -1570341200000
  - which is, 29/03/1920, 00:00:00 GMT+5:30
- The date object that is deseralized gets mapped to:

  - -1570339800000
  - which is, 29/03/1920, 00:23:20 GMT+5:30
- As you can see, the deserialized date is off by +1400 seconds.
- The marshaller that is being used is:

  - `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller`

Is there some default configuration at the client side which is making the deserialization off?

I am not familiar with JAXB, so please feel free and let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks,

Comment: In your POJO object, which class type `date` is ? Is it `java.util.Date` ?

Comment: @javaguy yes it is.